# Laravel white page 500 internal server error

Tags: php, laravel, apache2, composer-php, ubuntu-14.04

I have some problems with Laravel 5. I installed PHP and Apache on my server, I used composer to install Laravel with `composer create-project laravel/laravel foldername` but wenn I try to visit the /public folder in my browser I just see a white page and the dev log says a 500 internal server error.

In my apache error log I have the following:
`[Mon Aug 31 19:19:15.855570 2015] [:error] [pid 23556] [client 10.0.2.2:58505] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/test/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException), Array)\n#3 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(49): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException))\n#4 /var/www/test/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(33): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Ex in /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87
[Mon Aug 31 19:19:22.865065 2015] [:error] [pid 23557] [client 10.0.2.2:58507] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'The stream or file "/var/www/test/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened: failed to open stream: Permission denied' in /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php:87\nStack trace:\n#0 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/AbstractProcessingHandler.php(37): Monolog\\Handler\\StreamHandler->write(Array)\n#1 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(289): Monolog\\Handler\\AbstractProcessingHandler->handle(Array)\n#2 /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php(565): Monolog\\Logger->addRecord(400, Object(UnexpectedValueException), Array)\n#3 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Exceptions/Handler.php(49): Monolog\\Logger->error(Object(UnexpectedValueException))\n#4 /var/www/test/app/Exceptions/Handler.php(33): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Exceptions\\Handler->report(Object(UnexpectedValueException))\n#5 /var/www/test/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/ in /var/www/test/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Handler/StreamHandler.php on line 87`

I have like 20 or 30 of more or less the same entrys in my log.

I set the rights to:
`chown -R :www-data /var/www/test`
`chmod -R 755 /var/www/test`
`chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/storage`

Any ideas how I can get Laravel up and running?
(Homestead is not possible for my project)

Comment: What are the current permissions set on `/var/www/test/storage/logs/laravel.log`? Do a `ls -al /var/www/test/storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Comment: what about `chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/storage/logs/` ?

Comment: a 777 doesn´t change anything. In my folder is no laravel.log, the log folder is empty

Comment: wouldn't changing from 755 to 777 make the folders group-writable, which may be the problem?

Comment: @eragon-2006 who owns your www and project folder?

Answer (score 7):

According to the Laravel documentation( http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/configuration#after-installation), folders within storage and vendor should have write access by the web server.

I think you should run like this :

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/storage
chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/vendor
```

Comment: I created an laravel.log file with touch and yet I got a new error:
`ErrorException in Filesystem.php line 81:
file_put_contents(/var/www/html/servmin/storage/framework/views/d321637e45680774d1b2a91efcaf26b1): failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Comment: I've reproduced the same problem following what you did. It's all about permissions and ownership. Once I changed the ownership of the project like you, the laravel file system can't reach logs. I think you should ensure these : What permission and ownership is this file /var/www/html/servmin/storage/framework/views/d321637e45680774‌​d1b2a91efcaf26b1  (It should have same ownership as other files.)

Answer (score 0):

As @Binggre suggest, you should include this command as well

```
chmod -R 777 /var/www/test/bootstrap/cache
```